# example of a graph such that K(G)=δ(G)=Δ(G)E(G)

Tags: graph-theory

example of a graph such that K(G)=δ(G)=Δ(G), where K(G) is the number of components,δ(G) is the minimum degree of G and Δ(G) is the maximum degree in G.

Comment: How to prove If G is simple with δ(G)>=K(G) the G has a path of lenght k?

Comment: Where did $E(G)$ from the title go?

Comment: @draks. What do you mean? Thank you..

Comment: @Bayoy:  Your Question is not clear.  The title mentions $E(G)$ but this notation is not explained in the body of the Question, which seems to ask a slightly different problem.  Note that if the minimum and maximum degrees are equal, we say the graph is *regular*,

Comment: You might enjoy posting mathematical expressions with the site functionality of [MathJax](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and $\LaTeX$.

Answer (score 1):

A single <strike>vertex</strike> EDGE, two triangles, three tetrahedrons, ...

So a single edge has two vertices, both part of the same connected component. Both these vertices have a minimum and maximum degree of 1.

Comment: Ok, could you accept the answer then. It's not exhaustive of course! (three cubes? - three 3-regular graphs - 4 4-regular graphs, etc)

Comment: Is it possible that I have a graph G(one graph) and then K(G)=δ(G)=Δ(G)?

Comment: I don't understand the notation "G(one graph)" - do you mean a single connected component? That's K(G) - which can only be one for a single vertex graph : do you see why?

Comment: @ gilleain Yes, a single connected graph. Is it possible we can get K(G)=δ(G)=Δ(G)? I always thinking about this  for a couple of days.. I think its not possible..

Comment: Hmm. I was wrong but almost right - it's the graph consisting of a single EDGE. This has one connected component (K(G) = 1), both vertices have minimum degree of 1 (δ(G) = 1) and maximum degree of 1 (Δ(G) = 1)

Comment: @ Gilleain..I got it Gilleain.. Thank you so much..

Comment: @ gilleain.. What is the most simple example of of $v$ is not a cut vertex of $G$ complement then $v$ is a cut vertex of $G$?

Comment: @Bayoy I suggest you ask this as a new question